# Selenium [Java] : How can I make it wait until a table has been refreshed?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Assume that I have a web page that has records, **displayed in a table** ( that has several columns). Now there is **search-input-box** and a **search-button**. Using those **I am searching for records with an id in the table**.

**I am using implicit wait** which seems to be working fine in most of the cases and failing under this scenario :

- I made the page to load all the data in the table after I logged in using implicit wait
- Entered id in the search-input-box and clicked search-button
- Now I am expecting only one record instead of all the records that were
  displayed in the table before the search happened

It seems that **it did not find enough time to refresh the table** and still showing all the records even though I do search with ( for the id columns in the table):

```
List<WebElement> idRows = driver.wait(<waittime>, <interval>).until(driver -> driver.findElement(By.id("column-id")));
```

If I use **Thread.sleep()** after clicking the search-button, everything is fine as I am seeing the table has been refreshed with the expected result. However, I have to avoid using thread.sleep.

May I get any suggestion on how can I make it wait until the table has been refreshed with searched data?

Comment: _...I am expecting only one record instead of all the records..._ how about locating the same record using a search criteria from all the records?

Comment: Please add html source code or better provide url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the id is unique you are searching, in that case, you can do this:

After clicking the `search` button wait for the size of the records to be 1

```
wait.until(driver -> records.size() == 1);
```

In case when your searched `id` is not unique and after searching you can see multiple results, you can do it this way:

Before clicking the `search` button you can get the size of the records

```
int size = records.size();
```

After clicking the `search` button you can wait for the size of the records be decreased:

```
wait.until(driver -> records.size() < size);
```